# IFTTT EntryContent not generated from RSS

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, rss

While trying to automate things with IFTTT, I use a custom recipe to automatically post new articles from my WordPress site to a Facebook Page via RSS. Everything works except that no EntryContent is generated for the articles by IFTTT and posts on Facebook end up quite poor.

Is there a way to see how IFTTT posts look like before they get posted on Facebook?

Comment: Would you mind posting the feed url?

Comment: Not at all -> [The feed](http://contestwatchers.com/feed/)